# How to shift a list one more time than before each time?

Tags: python, list

**For example - a left shift:**

Here is a `grid` of letters for example

```
tiwxz          
shshq          
avidy          
bsvsc
```

This is the effect I want to have. The `X` symbol fills in the space created by the movement.

```
XXXtiwxz         # no shift
XXshshqX         # one shift left
XavidyXX         # two shift left
bsvscXXX         # three shift left
```

- The grid of letters would be a list where each row is an item
- I do not know how long the list is going to be
- Solution should be pure python

How would I do a left shift and a right shift for `grid`?

**This is all I have got:**

```
def diags(grid, rev=False):
    n = len(grid)
    _grid = [list(row) + [None]*(n-1) for row in grid]
```

Comment: Can you share your initial attempt? As written, this sounds like you’re asking a community of volunteers to write your python function.

Comment: stealththeninja I've added it

Comment: Seems these X's are appearing out of nowhere.

Comment: Jaba i said it in the question?

Comment: Yes, but just 3 of them or what amount are you trying to move them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pad the left and right sides with `X`s (or `None`s) based on the row's index which you can get with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
grid = [list(s) for s in 'tiwxz shshq avidy bsvsc'.split()]
new_grid = [(['X'] * (len(grid) - 1) + lst)[i:] + ['X'] * i for i, lst in enumerate(grid)]
```

**Output**

```
for l in new_grid:
    print(l)

# ['X', 'X', 'X', 't', 'i', 'w', 'x', 'z']
# ['X', 'X', 's', 'h', 's', 'h', 'q', 'X']
# ['X', 'a', 'v', 'i', 'd', 'y', 'X', 'X']
# ['b', 's', 'v', 's', 'c', 'X', 'X', 'X']
```

Comment: a solution for shifting from **slider** - hilarious :) but a good one. I removed all the trailing spaces to get rid of the scrollbars on your code.

Answer (score 3):

This function will do the job. To confirm backside spaces you can print the length of the string. input_grid is the list of a row as an element.

```
def formater_fn(input_grid):
    right_len = len(input_grid) + len(input_grid[0])
    left_len = len(input_grid) + len(input_grid[0])
    for item in input_grid:
        right_item = item.rjust(right_len)
        new_item = right_item.ljust(left_len)
        right_len = right_len-1
        print new_item
```